# how to find xpath of an element based on a number?

Tags: xpath

The issue I'm having is that I'm trying to find the xPath of the first element on a webpage that has more than 5 retweets.  I'm trying to test in Selenium WebDriver using a testNG file.  The page in question is the the following:

> http://example.crowdynews.com/crowdynews/usa/politics/

I know I can just right click and find the Firepath of the element for it, but I would like to make the code dynamic considering that the news site is a dynamic as well.

If anyone can let me know how to do that or that could point me to a comprehensive  site that could teach me how to do that, I would be very appreciative as I have yet to locate something that.

Comment: But that number will change frequently , then how you will be able to find element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is one possible XPath selector :**

```
//b[@class='kudos-count' and number(.)>5]/ancestor::div[@class='item-wrap li-link']
```

**brief explanation :**

- **`//b`** : find all `b` elements anywhere in the HTML document...
- **`[@class='kudos-count' and number(.)>5]`** : ...where `class` attribute equals `"kudos-count"` and the content of the element, after converted to number, is greater than 5
- **`/ancestor::div`** : from such `b` elements, return the ancestor `div` element...
- **`[@class='item-wrap li-link']`** : ...where `class` attribute equals `"item-wrap li-link"`. The class indicates the `div` that contains the entire individual news

Comment: Thank you for the explanation on how to locate an element based on specific directions.

However, when I tried putting that into my code, I get the following error:

`org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"b[@class='kudos-count' and number(.)>5]/ancestor::div[@class='item-wrap li-link']"}
Command duration or timeout: 10.86 seconds`

Comment: So that means it's not able to locate the an element. I used the following: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("b[@class='kudos-count' and number(.)>5]/ancestor::div[@class='item-wrap li-link']")).click();`

Comment: @Tscott looks like you missed the `//` at the beginning of the XPath : `//b[@class....`, it makes a real difference

Comment: Thank you!  Of course it was something as small as that.  Again, THANK YOU!  :)